# UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios5

i have search at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UITableView+dataSource+must+return+a+cell+from+tableView%3AcellForRowAtIndexPath ,but i know i need to check  if the cell is nil,but my cell is custom,and i am not use xib,i am  use storyboard.i am also choice the class CustomPlaceTableViewCell at storyboard.as https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0rRO.png

code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomPlaceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomPlaceTableViewCell class]]) { cell = (CustomPlaceTableViewCell *)cell; }
//retrieve the place info
Place *place = [self.placeDataController objectInPlaceListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//set the cell with place info
if (place.name)
{
    cell.nameLabel.text =place.name;
}
else
{
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"PortAura";
}

 if (place.distance)
{
    cell.distanceLabel.text = place.distance;    
}
else
{
    cell.distanceLabel.text = @"PortAura";
}



 return cell;

}


CustomPlaceTableViewCell.m
@interface CustomPlaceTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{
  UILabel *nameLabel;
  UILabel *distanceLabel;
  UILabel *addressLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
 @end


   @implementation CustomPlaceTableViewCell
   @synthesize distanceLabel,nameLabel,addressLabel;

  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
  }
 return self;
}

 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

  // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 @end
```

when i run my app ,it give me :

2012-07-02 17:16:26.675 MyAura[2595:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: we are not getting your question please make it clear like we can do something for you..

Comment: can you post the complete code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Ofcourse you should return it **return cell;**

Comment: i have add return cell,not useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first i used :

```
    PlaceMasterViewController *placeController = [[PlaceMasterViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:placeController animated:YES];
```

cause me no data in the table,or give  me the mistake,so i used:

```
  UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle: nil];

    PlaceMasterViewController *placeController = (PlaceMasterViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                                                       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"peoplemastViewControl"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:placeController animated:YES];
```

all is OK

Answer (score 4):

I think You miss return cell in  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath
try this

```
return cell;
```

ans check or use this `NSLog(@"description = %@",[cell description]);`

if `[cell description]` is null then change it

```
CustomPlaceTableViewCell *cell = (CustomPlaceTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: CustomPlaceTableViewCell.xib change class name from UITableViewCell to CustomPlaceTableViewCell

Comment: i am  not use xib,i am use storyboard,i have modify the CustomPlaceTableViewCell choice

Comment: hey please check your cell adreess, your cell address is nil, check again

Comment: use this  NSLog(@"description = %@",[cell description]);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13302/discussion-between-pengwang-and-elppa)

Comment: when you are come please ping me

Comment: thank you for your help me,through not give me the correct answer,but give me more clue.i give you one vote

Answer (score 2):

Yes your code will get crash even after you are using all suggestions above. Have you checked that your cell is actually being created??

No this is not being created and this method is actually returning a `nil` value.

Using following line in your code is trying to use reusable cell but what if there is no cell created??

```
CustomPlaceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

you have to check this after your code like:

```
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[CustomPlaceTableViewCell alloc] init]; // or your custom initialization
}
```

after this only your cell won't be nil and app won't get crash.

Hope this will solve your issues

Comment: through my app not crash,but the view not any data appear,it give me a no data table

Comment: you mensioned that `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'` thats why I answered accordingly.

Comment: yes,but if i am not use custom cell,i am use system cell,it  all is ok,but my label is more than system cell

Comment: @KapilChoubisa there is no need to check whether cell is created or not ie nil or not because he is using storyboard. And just make sure that the CellIdentifier name is same as whatever you have provided in properties while creating tableview using storyboard.

Comment: yes,the CellIdentifier is the same as properties while creating tableview using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same issue but I resolved it.

I am facing this issue because, I created my talbeViewCell in separate Xib file and I made my tableview class as File's owner. But, I haven't linked my cell IBOutlet to my tableview class.

So, linking my tableviewcell Xib to IBOutlet created in my tableview, I resolved this problem.

You will get this issue because your tableviewcell crated in cellforRowAtIndex is nil.

Answer (score -1):

`return cell;`  is missing at end