# iOS: UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, datasource, tableview

I've checked a few other questions but still can't figure out why this is happening. All I know is after using the description code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290746/uitableview-datasource-must-return-a-cell-from-tableviewcellforrowatindexpath) question the cell's value is `null`. I've set the `delegate` and `datasource` of the `table` correctly and I can't see where this is going wrong.

If I set the return value of the following method to 0, no error occurs because the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method doesn't really take place. So if I set it as 1 (as it should be) it'll then throw the error. I've synthesized the `NSArray` and checked that its populated (although that shouldn't matter I guess) and basically what is meant to happen is I press a `button` that searches and then places the results in the `table`. So before this the `tableview` is empty.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Here's the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method itself. I've tried just using the basic template method too, which still throws the same error.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSDictionary *aResult = [results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"RESULTS IN TABLE %i", [results count ]);


    id key = [results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    resultTitle.text=@"Hello";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[aResult objectForKey:@"url"]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [theTableView reloadData];

    return cell;
}
```

I've no idea what is wrong. I've used `tableviews` before and have compared this project to others to see if I've missed something, but I can't see any real differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are not initisialing the cell if nil is returned from the dequeue method

change

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Excellent, that fixed it. Description is no longer null so I can now move onto formatting the cell. Thank you, I'll accept the answer in a minute when it lets me.

Comment: @Stavash not true, there will be a new method for dequeue-ing a cell, but the current method will still be there

Comment: FYI - Using Storyboards and iOS5+ guarantees that `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` always returns a cell

Comment: @Stavash not exactly. I dont think we can mention methods because of the NDA but the behaviour of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: does not change under iOS6, but there is a new method with different behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a method to return the number of rows in section 0 - this is a required data source method (in this case).